# How to make CSS grid wrap content w/ repeat()?

Tags: css, layout, grid, overflow

Im trying to make a layout with overflow, but my columns are not the same size. Usually all answers propose this solution.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

**BUT,** I need to overflow grid columns that are different but fixed in size.

```
// Overflow this when one of the columns meet max-content.
grid-template-columns: 5fr 7fr;
```

Comment: Then perhaps Css-grid is not exactly what you want.

Comment: can you define *overflow* ?